# setTimeout does nothing

Tags: javascript, delay, settimeout

I am trying add a delay in execution for a function call inside a do while loop, however when it comes to that line in the code there is no delay. Here is the loop that it does not work in:

```
delay = parseInt(delay * 1000);
    for (var i = gamesplayed; i<numgames; i++){
            do{
                    $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: 'cs316program3.php',
                            data: {player1name:player1name.value, player2name:player2name.value, playtopoints:playtopoints.value, delay:delay.value, numgames:numgames.value, gamesplayed:gamesplayed.value, p1turn:p1turn.value, p2turn:p2turn.value, p1total:p1total.value, p2total:p2total.value},
                            success: function(data)
                            {
                                    rolling = data;
                            }
                    });
                    alert(delay);
                    setTimeout(function { roll() }, delay);                           

            }while (rolling == 1);
```

I have tried different variations of the setTimeout call such as :

```
setTimeout(roll,delay);
setTimeout(roll(),delay);
setTimeout(function {roll();},delay);
```

Yet none of actually put in a delay, they either dont work or just have no delay.

Edit: I should say that this loop calls a php file that returns either a 1 or 0 to continue looping if it is a 1

Comment: Code makes no sense. The do while loop is going to lock up. Use a callback, do not try to implement a sleep/wait.

Comment: Functions called with `setTimeout` are not run until the browser returns to the main event loop. As long as you're in your `while` loop, you'll never get there. The same goes with the AJAX callback, so it will never update `rolling`, so the loop never exits.

Comment: The first and third are the correct ways to write the `setTimeout` call.